# VMWare not recognizing my android phone (the device was unable to connect to its ideal host controller)

Tags: android, vmware-player

I need to do some Android development under Linux using VMWare. I can't get it to work, and VM keeps saying

`the device was unable to connect to its ideal host controller`

I have seen some developers doing successively. Since ADB won't connect; therefore I can't do much. I need a physical device attached to the Ubuntu VM.

anyone know how to get pass this issue? VMWare forums is pretty useless and this is the version I am using:

17.5.0 build-22583795

and the possible work around that did not work either.

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Device-unable-to-connect-to-preferred-ideal-host-controller/td-p/529784

attached is the full error below.

thank you in advance for any possible hints.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The guys at VMWare answered me. You need to set the VM player to a compatible with the USB type of your host, in my case 3.1.

[image]

I will leave this thread around, since I am sure someone else may have faced the issue.

Solution:

Complete answer:

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/VMWare-not-recognizing-droid-phone-the-device-was-unable-to/m-p/3000987